# Are modules and classes implemented as constants?

Tags: ruby

When I call a class or module like this:

```
module Somemodule
end

class Someclass
end
```

are these the same as when I set them as constants?

```
Somemodule = Module.new
Someclass = Class.new
```

Are `Somemodule` and `Someclass` simply constants that represent `Module.new` and `Class.new`?

Answer (score 0):

All your questions have answers in [The Pickaxe](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0).

```
class ‹ scope:: › classname ‹ < superexpr ›
    body
end
```

> A Ruby class definition creates or extends an object of class Class by
>   executing the code in body. In the first form, a named class is
>   created or extended. The resulting Class object is assigned to a
>   constant named classname (keep reading for scoping rules). This name
>   should start with an uppercase letter. ...

```
module name
    body
end
```

> A module is basically a class that cannot be instantiated. Like a
>   class, its body is executed during definition, and the resulting
>   Module object is stored in a constant.

`Class.new( super_class=Object ) ‹{…}›` → cls

> Creates a new anonymous (unnamed) class with the given superclass (or
>   Object if no parameter is given). If called with a block, that block
>   is used as the body of the class.

`Module.new` → mod

`Module.new {|mod| … }` → mod

> Creates a new anonymous module. If a block is given, it is passed the
>   module object, and the block is evaluated in the context of this
>   module using module_eval.

There is something interesting about the name :

```
some_class = Class.new
obj        = some_class.new
puts "Initial name is #{some_class.name.inspect}"

SomeClass = some_class
puts "After assigning to the constant SomeClass, the name is #{some_class.name}"
puts "also works via the object: #{obj.class.name}"
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
Initial name is nil
After assigning to the constant SomeClass, the name is SomeClass
also works via the object: SomeClass
```

**Update**

> Are Somemodule and Someclass simply constants that represent
>   Module.new and Class.new?

Certainly not. `Module.new` creates an instance of class `Module` whose pointer is stored in the constant `Somemodule`. `Class.new` creates an instance of class `Class` whose pointer is stored in the constant `Someclass`.

For

```
class Someclass
end
```

and

```
Someclass = Class.new
```

from the definitions above and the fact that an unnamed class becomes named after assignment to a constant, I'm almost sure it's the same thing, but I'm not an expert. Consult answers of Gurus like [Jörg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%C3%B6rg-w-mittag).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but just wondering, are they equal (creating a new class/module via class and module keywords, and assigning them to a constant like shown above?)

Comment: @the12 Updated.

Comment: @the12: there are some differences, e.g. a module and class definition body is its own local variable scope, whereas `Module.new` and `Class.new` take blocks which have *nested* local variable scope and are closures. Also, `Foo = Module.new` will *always* overwrite whatever `Foo` referenced before, whereas `module Foo` will *re-open* `Foo` if it was a module before, and be an error if it was something else.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Right... I suppose those would be additional details of how instantiating differs from using the keyword method. But  just wanted to be 100% sure that the constants `Somemodule/SomeClass = Module.new/Class.new` is the same thing as `module Somemodule/class Someclass` ? Just wanted to confirm with a senior programmer :)